# How to change this dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have go a dynamic query witch create new table from data in #Table.
I want to change that query to have a CreateDate field in create statment.
But I don't have idea how I can do this.

```
create table #Table
(

    [SchemaName] nvarchar(100) not null
    ,[TableName] nvarchar(128) not null
    ,[FieldId] int  
    ,[ColumnName] nvarchar(100)
    ,FieldDefinitionID int
    ,Ordinal int 
    ,[Data Type] nvarchar(100)
    ,IsNullable bit
    ,IsIdentity bit
    ,HasDefault bit 
    ,DefaultName nvarchar(100)
    ,DefaultDefinition  nvarchar(100)
    ,[Description] nvarchar(100) 
    ,HasCheckConstraint bit  
    ,CheckConstraintName bit 
    ,CheckConstraintDefinition bit 
    ,PartitionIndexKey bit 
    ,ObjectID int 


);



insert into #Table
            (
                [SchemaName] 
                ,[TableName] 
                ,[FieldId]   
                ,[ColumnName]   
                ,Ordinal 
                ,[Data Type] 
                ,IsNullable 
                ,IsIdentity
                ,HasDefault 
                ,HasCheckConstraint
            )
            select 
            N'dbo'
            ,N'test'
            ,-6
            ,N'RecordId'
            ,1
            ,N'int'
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0



insert into #Table
            (
                [SchemaName] 
                ,[TableName] 
                ,[FieldId]   
                ,[ColumnName]   
                ,Ordinal 
                ,[Data Type] 
                ,IsNullable 
                ,IsIdentity
                ,HasDefault 
                ,HasCheckConstraint
            )
            select 
            N'dbo'
            ,N'test'
            ,-6
            ,N'RecordId'
            ,1
            ,N'int'
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0
            ,0



select          N'

    create table [' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'].[' + [t].[TableName] + N']
    (
        [' 
        + [t].[ColumnName] 
        + N'] ' 
        + [t].[Data Type] 
        + case
            when [t].[IsNullable] = 0
            then N' not null '
            else N' null '
        end
        + case
            when [t].[IsIdentity] = 1
            then N' identity '
            else N''
        end
        + case
            when [t].[HasDefault] = 1
            then N' constraint [' + [t].[DefaultName] + N'] default ' + [t].[DefaultDefinition]
            else N''
        end
        +
        N'
    );

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''EntityId''
                                    ,@value = N''' + cast(11 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                    ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                    ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''MessageId''
                                    ,@value = N''' + cast(3456 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                    ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                    ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

    ' 


    from  #Table t
```

This select gives me that result:

```
    create table [dbo].[test]
    (
        [RecordId] int not null 
    );

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'EntityId'
                                    ,@value = N'11'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MessageId'
                                    ,@value = N'3456'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';
```

but I want to have a CreateDate field in create table statment just like this:

```
    create table [dbo].[test]
    (
        [RecordId] int not null 
        ,[CreateDate] datetime not null
    );

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'EntityId'
                                    ,@value = N'11'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';

    exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MessageId'
                                    ,@value = N'3456'
                                    ,@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = N'dbo'
                                    ,@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = N'test';
```

but I don't know how to change my query to get this result.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the literal text to the string being generated. Update the query to be:

```
select          N'

create table [' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'].[' + [t].[TableName] + N']
(
    [' 
    + [t].[ColumnName] 
    + N'] ' 
    + [t].[Data Type] 
    + case
        when [t].[IsNullable] = 0
        then N' not null '
        else N' null '
    end
    + case
        when [t].[IsIdentity] = 1
        then N' identity '
        else N''
    end
    + case
        when [t].[HasDefault] = 1
        then N' constraint [' + [t].[DefaultName] + N'] default ' + [t].[DefaultDefinition]
        else N''
    end
    +
    N'
    ,[CreateDate] datetime not null
);

exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''EntityId''
                                ,@value = N''' + cast(11 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name = N''MessageId''
                                ,@value = N''' + cast(3456 as nvarchar(max)) + N'''
                                ,@level0type = N''Schema'', @level0name = N''' + [t].[SchemaName] + N'''
                                ,@level1type = N''Table'', @level1name = N''' + [t].[TableName] + N''';

' 
from  #Table t
```

Comment: It works :) , but what in case when I don't know the second field name and I want to get it in dynamic way from #Table? is this possilbe?

Comment: It is possible, but the current table structure doesn't look like it has a field for secondary column definitions.

Comment: I mean that not always the second field will be CreateDate so i want to get this name in dynamic way from #Table.

Comment: @NewMe You really need to ask a new question because that is not what this question asked.